# Merge javascript files in runtime

Tags: javascript, merge, runtime

So, I got a big menu with a couple of sub-items under each menu-item. Each sub-item needs javascript-includes and in some (pretty often) cases there are 20~ includes. This obviously sucks considering the HTTP-request time blah blah.

My thoughts are the following. I'm creating a merger-file (in PHP) that will handle all the js-includes and make them into one big file. But I got some questions.

There are two cases.

1. A merger file is created for each sub-item and stored in a special folder. Each sub-item will then include that file, and only that file that is "it's own js-file"

Pros: Very clear that a certain sub-item got it's own js-file.
Cons: A lot of files and also each time you make a change in a js-file you have to update the merged js-file manually

1. A merger file is created on the fly for each sub-item depending on some parameters (js.php?modules=jquery-jqueryui-plugin1-plugin2)

Pros: Easy to work with, all changes will be updated instantly since it's generated in runtime.
Cons: The possibility that the processing time and energy to create the merger-file will even out the loss of 20~ HTTP requests.

So, this is a question about performance. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could also cache the dynamic file.  For a given, unique URL you'd only generate the file once, and write it to a physical file.  You could then redirect any subsequent request to that physical file.